# Oracle Custom User Defined Type ReadSql Stream in a type safe method

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Hi I use simplejdbccall and storedprocedure to make database call.In my stored procedure I have some userdefinedtypes in my output.I can read this output class with help of SQLData and set my own java object model.

Myproblem is when I want to read SqlStream ,all properties must be same order in database model.Is it possible to it with type safe method.
What I want when I want to change order of properties that time I want to match correct value.
In this solution when I change order that time all values are mixed and wrong.

```
public class MY_INFO implements SQLData, UserDefinedType {
    private int tn_prop1;
    private int tn_prop2;
    private String ts__info;


public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    return "xxxx.MY_INFO";
}

public void readSQL(SQLInput sqlInput, String string) throws SQLException {

    setTn_prop1(sqlInput.readInt());
    setTn_prop2(sqlInput.readInt());
    setTs__info(sqlInput.readString());
```